# Is there a replacement glass panel for iPad that is "matte"?

Tags: ipad, screen, repair

I had broken my Unibody MacBook screen and took the opportunity to replace it with a matte screen, [via TechRestore](http://www.techrestore.com/mac/mbp-unibody-repair.shtml).  I loved the improvement, as I dislike glossiness in almost every context.  [Even my car is painted matte!](http://mrgray.com/dir/slick/#/?album=2&zoom=22)

[image]

[image]

Anyways, I stupidly broke the glass on my **3G iPad1** today and want to **replace the glass with a "matte" version.**..  Is there anything like this anywhere?
I know I can get a film or what not, but it's just not as satisfying.  So far, I've found a steady stream of probably-good-enough faux-OEM glass panels on eBay starting at $50 each (with the hilariously name spooge tool, included!)
But they're all glossy!!  I hate the gloss!!

**Does anyone know where I can get some matte replacement glass for my iPad?**

Comment: Theyre analogies @bmike.... get it... chuckle chuckle. And can you point me to the which line it is that i start pining of my forced consumer-buying patterns?  i have two iPads, i speak with emotion, and if i'm not mistaken... you're the one trolling.. as you've now downvoted both of the posts i made today and then copied my response as an answer, to boot... thanks for adding the pictures though!

Comment: @bmike does have a solid point. Those analogies are unnecessary and could be found offensive. In any case, they don't add to your post.I have edited your post to remove the problem material, but please keep this sort of thing out of your future posts. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: no offense intended. I'll delete my comment about the words that Nathan edited. Let me know if I can help - I only get one vote (and I've up voted this post as is for the record - so you'll have to worry about other people down voting your posts.) I bet this gets lots more up votes as it stands as it's a really good question.

Comment: <chuckle> My curiosity made me go and see what has been edited… @alex this is your 2nd question/comment on this "STACK"[sic] and one of them has been somewhat offensive towards the people who roams here and donates time. By saying that the site is "redundant" and posting offensive analogies towards certain products, you're not really helping. I'm not a mod, so all I can do is express my opinion. I happen to have a huge 30'' glossy screen I love to use at night to watch movies… see, the *cancer* is not always evil. Do I love Glossy? Nope. But it has places.

Comment: trust me, I wish i was less abrasive, it would serve me well in life. but like big glossy screens, we are dealt the hand we've got... and have to just try to get  through the game ;-)  redundant:_yes_ :: when in Rome:_I'm here aren't I?_   re: glossiness; But why did apple change their "lustre" after all these years?  Was it the perception of better saturation prevalent in the consumer space (as Steve has mentioned), do you think?  i liked the old, belligerent apple (most of the time), that never bowed to misguided, end-user-tendencies that resulted in a net loss of actual functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would:

- repair screen at [local apple authorized service provider](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?q=local%20authorized%20apple%20service)
- cover new new screen with a new [matte screen protector for ipad](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?q=Matte%20ipad%20screen%20protector) <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Please read reviews before buying one, because some people complain about different issues like a little blurred screen, grain etc.